# Laravel Eloquent hasMany Relation with Grouping and Sorting

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.6 and would like to get a collection of featured articles published in the last 2 weeks sorted by the number of views over the last week.  Ideally using pagination on the model.

DB:

```
author (id, name, ....)
article (id, title, content, publish_date, ...)
article_view (id, article_id, date, views)
featured_article (id, article_id, created_at)
```

Models

```php
class Author extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'author';
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class,'id','author_id');
    }
}

class Article extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'article';
   public function author()
   {
        return $this->hasOne(Author::class,'id','author_id');
   }
}

class FeaturedArticle extends Model
{ 
   protected $table = 'featured_article';
   static public function getFeaturedArticles($limit)
   {
     $articles = FeaturedArticles::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))->with(['article.author','article.articleViews'])->paginate($limit);
   }
}
```

Then in the Controller or Feature or Job

```php
$featured_articles = FeaturedArticle::getFeaturedArticles(15);
```

This works fine, but the results aren't sorted yet. How to sort the paginated results by the sum of article_view.views over 7 days.  Is it possible?

Comment: You could try whereHas() with a callback if you want to keep it eloquent. If not then a simple join would be easy to query with the Query Builder.

Comment: From [Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination) 
"Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually."

So then this issue is only with sorting the result.

Comment: I tried grouping on the relationship, but mysql would have nothing of it:
     
"SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column"

Any way to sort in the FeaturedArticle function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the most viewed article first:

```php
class FeaturedArticle extends Model
{
    public function articleViews() {
        return $this->hasMany(ArticleView::class, 'article_id', 'article_id');
    }
}

$articles = FeaturedArticle::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays(14))
    ->withCount(['articleViews' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('sum(views)'))
            ->where('date', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays(7));
    }])
    ->orderByDesc('article_views_count')
    ->with('article.author', 'article.articleViews')
    ->paginate($limit);
```

I replaced `Carbon::now()` with `Carbon::today()`. Otherwise, you wouldn't get articles that were published 14 days ago before the time of `now()`.

Also, your relationships are incorrect:

```php
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'author_id', 'id');
}

public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: hello, sir. could you please check out this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099300/eloquent-groupby-is-not-working-correctly-on-table-relations