# Eloquent groupBy() is not working correctly on table relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The `groupBy` method isn't working correctly. I am not sure what is the problem.

### UPDATED

I made made a `hasMany()` <-> `belongsTo()` relations between tables.

Place `model`

```
protected $table = "places";
protected $guarded = [];

public $with = ["plans"];

public function plans()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Plan");
}
```

Plan `Model`

```
protected $guarded = [];

public function place()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Place");
}
```

In **controller** when I return json data I can see the relation.

```
$place = Place::with(["plans"])->get();

return $place;
```

The result is fine with this. check the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0TTg.jpg

But, when I try to use `groupBy()` on `place_name` column. It doesn't group the their plans in one place...

```
Place::with(["plans"])->groupBy("place_name")->get();
```

and the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYyfZ.jpg

As you see second place's plan doesn't group with first place... it's gone unknown... Expected result plan object should grouped too because their `place_name` grouped...

Any idea what's causing this problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a problem that sometimes two rows are grouping due to group by, then you can do one thing. You can use group by concat both fields.

```
$data = Place::groupBy(\DB::raw('CONCAT(name, ' ', address)'))->paginate();
```

This is the logic you can put and get desire result.

Comment: I tried it, but there is an error. says `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::groupByRaw()`

Comment: I updated the question. could you please check it out?

Comment: @Tay In Laravel, relational data load after main query execution. When main query execute then fetch relationship id and load data from relationship. If you want to group relational data on the basis of group by in main query then you have to create your own query to get relational data instead of laravel relationship.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$data = Place::groupBy(['name','address'])->paginate(20);
```